# Writing a Distinct LINQ query with a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following LINQ query to fill up my model.

```
var blogs = (from b in Context.Blogs
                    select new BlogTreeView
                               {
                                   Created = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(b.Created),
                                   Children = (from ba in Context.Blogs
                                               where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(ba.Created) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(b.Created)
                                               select new BlogTitle
                                                          {
                                                              ID = ba.ID,
                                                              Title = ba.Title
                                                          })
                               }).Distinct();
```

The problem is that the distinct gives the following error:
"The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.\r\nParameter name: argument"

I also tried this:

```
var blogs = (from b in Context.Blogs
                    select new BlogTreeView
                               {
                                   Created = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(b.Created)
                               }).Distinct();
```

This gives me only the unique dates like I want.

Then I've tried to add the childrens to the model with the help of a foreach:

```
        foreach (var item in blogs)
        {
            item.Children = (from ba in Context.Blogs
                             where
                                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(ba.Created) ==
                                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(item.Created)
                             select new BlogTitle
                             {
                                 ID = ba.ID,
                                 Title = ba.Title
                             });
        }
```

But then my return value is null for the children list. In my foreach loop the Children list has the values that I want but not in the return field.

What am I doing wrong, and why did the first query gave me that error?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to be distinct.

Comment: My created date has to be distinct. I want to create a treeview by month. For example: September--subtitle October--subtitle

Comment: That sounds like you want to be *grouping* children by month, which isn't an appropriate case for Distinct() at all...

Comment: With the children list in the linq query I get duplicate months in my treeview. That I tried to solve with adding Distinct to it because then my duplicate values would not be shown. But then I get that error. When I only do a Distinct on the date it gives me no duplicates but the I can't add my childrens to the list.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider your approach. Group by month, and then create an entry for each group.